# Httpresponse 403 while access azure purview using Java SDK in ItelliJ IDEA

Tags: azure, azure-authentication, azure-purview, azure-sdk-for-java

I created one maven project in ItelliJ IDEA tool and add dependence azure-analytics-purview-catalog;azure-identity;azure-core-experimental;azure-core. BTW I have permission to access azure purview account in azure portal

here is my code content

```
    EntityBaseClient client = new PurviewCatalogClientBuilder()
            .endpoint("https://signofftest0517.catalog.purview.azure.com")
            .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
            .buildEntityBaseClient();
            DynamicRequest  request= client.getByGuid("3bb7fcf9-50ec-4218-97fb-25ac0a459e37");

            //3bb7fcf9-50ec-4218-97fb-25ac0a459e37  364e4e74-eb7c-4358-96bc-9b750cf275e2
            DynamicResponse  response=   request.send();
            int status= response.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println(status);
```

running results:
[image]

Comment: Authenticating a service principal with a client secret could resolve this issue ,refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Azure-Identity-Examples#authenticating-a-user-account-with-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Wang Thank you for your answer.

As mentioned in the Git hub link, Authenticating with client secret will work.